# CSS background-size property

Tags: html, css, background, background-size

I want to add a full-size background to my website, preferably only using the CSS properties `background` and `background-size`. Currently I am using the following

```
.bg {
  background: url("./gfxGeneral/backgroundImage.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And then `<body class="bg">` to apply it. The issue is that if the window becomes very narrow, the landscape style background image I am using, only covers a small part, since it is scaling itself to 100% of the width. Is there anyhow I can get it to use *either* 100% width or 100% height, in a way that never leaves any white background? I have found some guides for this, but all of them involves rather "ugly" code.

Bonus request: Preferably using code that supports older browsers like IE9

Comment: why you didn't just ask google for "css background size" ?

Comment: I did that, but none of the "simple" solutions I found have worked for me. I wanted to ask you guys before moving on to the overly complex solutions.

Comment: Also, the option ´background-size: 100% 100%;´ makes the background image full width but only like 10-15 pixels in height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the other answers are proposing only works if your `body` element is as big as the window.

If the `body` size is not the full window size, you could try using JavaScript (I'm using the jQuery framework):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Call the function at the beginning, in case the window is already too small, 
    onResize();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        onResize();
    });

    function onResize() {
        // Note: 16 / 9 is the resolution of the background image
        // Change appropriately
        if ($(window).width() / $(window).height() < 16 / 9) {
            $(".bg").css("background-size", "auto " + $(window).height() + "px");
        }
        else {
            $(".bg").css("background-size", "cover");
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

See [this JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9ggm2u1/3/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This actually works, I do have 2 short questions though:
1. Why is the body element not at least the same height as the window?
2. Is there some way to make it center the background, at least horizontally?

Comment: @Noceo I'll try to answer your questions: 1) the body element is just a container for all the other html elements, and adjusts its own height according to the elements contained. If there are no elements inside of it, its height will be 0.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to make it full height? Tried adding ´min-height: 100%´ in the css for the body element.

Comment: @Noceo 2) there is the css attribute `background-position` with which you can align your image. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) have some information about it. Try using `background-position: center top;`

Comment: @Noceo to make it full height use `html, body { min-height: 100%; }`. Doing some research, I actually found a way to do it without Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/so2f5fq3/

Comment: I must have been using it wrong, since I could not get it to work. Thanks a lot for your assistance, it now looks as awesome as I hoped it would :-).

Answer (score 0):

try this using css:

```
.bg {
  background: url("./gfxGeneral/backgroundImage.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;             //x% y%, first is width and second is height
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Its like I accidentally made the layout in such a way that it is not able to find the full height of the browser window. This causes this method to create some really odd looking issues in both background height and placement of elements (like <div>)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using javascript, you can use CSS "min-height" and "vh" unit to force the body element to be at least as high as viewport:

http://jsfiddle.net/s9ggm2u1/5/

```
body.bg {
    background[...]

    min-height: 100vh;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Browsers support for vh unit:
http://caniuse.com/#search=vh